# Is `history.go` case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, browser-history

In javascript is the `history.go` method case-insensitive when it comes to going to a url. As in if the actual url is `Login.html` and I passed in `login.html` would it go to `Login.html` if it was in history?

I read on `w3schools`:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp

> The parameter can either be a number which goes to the URL within the specific position (-1 goes back one page, 1 goes forward one page), or a string. The string must be a partial or full URL, and the function will go to the first URL that matches the string.

But then on `MDN` they have no info on this functionality with `go`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Moving_to_a_specific_point_in_history

> You can use the go() method to load a specific page from session history, identified by its relative position to the current page (with the current page being, of course, relative index 0).

So does `history.go(url)` even work? or do I need to use `history.go(number)`

---

If the case is that it is case sensitive then would it be possible to make it case-insensitive (which is probably a no)

---

**EDIT**

IE appears to be the only browser to support passing a url to it, going by `elclanrs` answer.

So lets divert the question a bit. Is there any way I could do this? Or create this kind of functionality?

Comment: In general don't use w3schools better look into the MDN sites. By the way it would be nice if you would link to the docs which you are citeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also from the MDN on [history.go(integerDelta)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history):

> Loads a page from the session history... Calling go() without
>   parameters or with a non-integer argument has no effect (**unlike
>   Internet Explorer, which supports string URLs as the argument**).

So I suppose that's the important bit you missed.

Comment: And there is no way I am supporting IE xD. Are there any work arounds?

Comment: You could just use `window.location.href = url` I guess...

Comment: I want to go back in history though. And delete those pages in between from history so the user doesn't go back to them.

Comment: Then I'd look into the History API in modern browsers, `popstate`, `pushstate`, etc...

Comment: Needs full support by safari. Appears to be limited support according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/popstate

Comment: More specifically mobile devices including `Android 2.2 and 2.3`

Comment: There are polyfills, specifically history.js.

Comment: Also states aren't what I am looking for. I want to specifically go back to a certain page. No change the state of the current page